# Javascript/Node.JS - is it possible to have a var with multiple definitions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, var

Is it possible to have a variable be defined as two different things without using an array?

So for example:

```
var myVar = "asd" || "fgh" // or maybe it's "asd" && "fgh"?
var message = "asdtest"
var otherMessage = "fghtest"
if (message === myVar + "test") {
   console.log("success!")
}
else if (otherMessage === myVar + "test") {
   console.log("success!")
}
```

Comment: Nope, that's why there's conditions and assignment, though.

Comment: @PHPglue true  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a variable can only hold a single thing at a time. If you want multiple things, you should use an array.

> var myVar = "asd" || "fgh"

This line of code will evaluate `"asd"` to see if it is 'truthy', and it is. Therefore, myVar is set to "asd". If instead it were 'falsy', for example if you did `var myVar = null || "fgh"`, then it would set myVar to the second part, thus making it equal "fgh".

Answer (score 2):

This is just one definition. The variable will be assigned to the value of the expression on the right side. In principle, this is the same thing as

```
var x = 1 + 2;
```

How `||` works is that it is logical OR: It returns the first ["truthy" value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (such as a non-empty String, all values are truthy unless they are `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, or `NaN`). This is useful if you want to give defaults to "missing" values for example:

```
var size = specifiedSize || 100;
```

In your case, it is simply `asd`.

Answer (score 1):

A variable can only hold a single value. However, your variable can be referencing an array or an object, which can hold more than one value.

Answer (score 1):

You may use objects or arrays to store all possible values:

```
var myVarObj = {
  p1: "asd"
  p2: "fgh"
};

var myVarArr = ["asd", "fgh"];

for (var property in myVarObj) {
    if (message === myVarObj[property] + "test") {
        console.log("success!");
    }
}

for (var value in myVarArr) {
    if (message === value + "test") {
        console.log("success!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function expression

```js
var myVar = bool => bool ? "asd" : "fgh";

console.log(myVar(1)); // `"asd"`
console.log(myVar(0)); // `"fgh"`
```